# Issue with getting sortable columns on associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to do sortable columns like here: [#228 Sortable Table](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns)

Models:
person.rb

```
# Table name: people
#
#  id                         :integer          not null, primary key
#  first_name                 :string           not null
#  last_name                  :string           not null
```

individual_traning.rb

```
# Table name: individual_trainings
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  date_of_training :date             not null
#  client_id        :integer
#  trainer_id       :integer
```

Associations:
  person.rb

```
  has_many :individual_trainings_as_trainer,
           class_name: 'IndividualTraining',
           foreign_key: 'trainer_id'
  has_many :individual_trainings_as_client,
           class_name: 'IndividualTraining',
           foreign_key: 'client_id'
```

individual_training.rb

```
  belongs_to :trainer, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: 'trainer_id'
  belongs_to :client, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: 'client_id'
```

individual_trainings_controller.rb

```
def index
    @individual_trainings = IndividualTraining.includes(:training_cost)
                                              .includes(:client)
                                              .order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction)
                                              .references(:training_costs)
                                              .references(:clients)
end

JOINED_TABLE_COLUMNS = %w(training_costs.cost training_costs.duration
                            clients.first_name).freeze
  def sort_column
    if JOINED_TABLE_COLUMNS.include?(params[:sort]) || IndividualTraining.column_names.include?(params[:sort])
      params[:sort]
    else
      'date_of_training'
    end
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w(asc desc).include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : 'asc'
  end
```

Issue:
When in view I use e.g. sortable "clients.first_name" there is error like this:

```
 PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "clients"
LINE 1: ...d" = "individual_trainings"."client_id"  ORDER BY clients.fi...
```

I used sortable on multiple associations and all was working. I supose that problem is in customized names of belongs_to(instead one belongs_to :people). Anyone have idea why my solution isn't correct?